# Haskell: Create a show instance for 2 dimensional ZipLists

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I wanted to create a show instance for 2 dimensional ziplists with a type of `ZipList (ZipList a)`. The below is my attempt.

```
import Control.Applicative

showMatrixZipList :: (Show a) => ZipList (ZipList a) -> String
showMatrixZipList = unlines . getZipList .  fmap (unwords . getZipList . fmap show)

instance (Show a) => Show (ZipList (ZipList a)) where
    show matrix = showMatrixZipList matrix
```

The code only compiles with `FlexibleInstances`, but can only execute `show $ ZipList [ZipList [1,2,3]]` with `OverlappingInstances`, but it then screws up the `show (ZipList [1,2,3])`, which can be fixed with `IncoherentInstances`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}
```

Is there a better way to do the above?

Comment: `ZipList a` already has a `Show` instance if `a` is showable, including `Show a => ZipList (ZipList a))`. That will lead to problems (and ambiguity). I strongly suggest a `newtype MatrixZipList a = ZipList (ZipList a)`.

Comment: Ah yes, there's already an instance. Perhaps I can override it just for 2 dimensional ziplists? Shouldn't that be a `type MatrixZipList` not `newtype`? Oh maybe you mean `newtype Matrix a = Matrix (ZipList (ZipList a))` and use the newtype as an instance.

Comment: You cannot "override" instances. By the way, this is one of the reasons you don't want to have orphan instances (e.g. instances which are neither defined where the data type, or the class is defined), as it can get messy and ambiguous if you accidentally import two instances of the same class. And yes, I meant `newtype Matrix = Matrix ...`, see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Note: This post is written in [literate Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming). You can save it as Matrix.lhs and try it in your GHCi.</sub>

---

The problem is that you're trying to define an instance [that already exists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Control.Applicative.html#line-126):

```
instance Show a => Show (ZipList a) where
  -- ...
```

Instead, define your own `Matrix` type:

```
newtype Matrix a = Matrix (ZipList (ZipList a))
```

However, since `ZipList a` is basically a wrapper around `[a]`, you can also simplify this to

```
> newtype Matrix a = Matrix {getMatrix :: [[a]] }
```

I guess you were using `ZipList` due to its `Functor` and `Applicative` instances, so let's provide them for `Matrix`:

```
> instance Functor Matrix where
>   fmap f = Matrix . fmap (fmap f) . getMatrix

> instance Applicative Matrix where
>   pure x                      = Matrix [[x]]
>   (Matrix as) <*> (Matrix bs) = Matrix $ zipWith (zipWith id) as bs
```

Now you can write your own `Show` instance, which won't overlap:

```
> showMatrix :: (Show a) => Matrix a -> String
> showMatrix = unlines . fmap (unwords . fmap show) . getMatrix

> instance Show a => Show (Matrix a) where
>   show = showMatrix
```

If you already wrote some functions for `ZipList (ZipList a)`, you can easily use them on `Matrix` too:

```
type ZipMatrix a = ZipList (ZipList a)

someZipFunc :: ZipMatrix a -> ZipMatrix a
someZipFunc = -- ...

someMatrixFunc :: Matrix a -> Matrix a
someMatrixFunc = coerce . someZipFunc . coerce
```

where [`coerce` is from `Data.Coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) and converts between types of the same representation (both `ZipMatrix a` and `Matrix a` are essentially `[[a]`). That way you don't have to rewrite all your current functions from scratch.

Comment: That's basically it. Thanks.